# How to create a timesheet dashboard in Google script HTML web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a dashboard in Google script HTML web app, the data consist, assigned project and total time spent on project by user

I have used some HTML code however it got jumbled, sharing the google sheet which consists data  I want to replicate this data in the web app.Functions I am looking here is "Date Picker" "User name / Project name" are the search parameters

The dashboard should reflect according to the search parameters and data should consist Total worked users by the user or total hours or users spent on the project.

I know it's bit complex, if your refer my sheet you will get some idea what I am looking to publish in web app

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n658SfT-rmIQJF-siW3YqyUVZhsIwBlSRHS5K1_OpkI/edit#gid=423511407)

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1Xr_zcL0hnfmKoECytosdgv2kffdalCdfe0ildF-_Re4')
      .getSheetByName('Sheet4')
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}

function getData1() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1Xr_zcL0hnfmKoECytosdgv2kffdalCdfe0ildF-_Re4')
      .getSheetByName('Sheet5')
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}


function getData2() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1Xr_zcL0hnfmKoECytosdgv2kffdalCdfe0ildF-_Re4')
      .getSheetByName('Sheet6')
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}

function getData3() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1Xr_zcL0hnfmKoECytosdgv2kffdalCdfe0ildF-_Re4')
      .getSheetByName('Sheet7')
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
    footer {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 25px;
    }

    .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */
      min-height: 200px;
    }

   
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">User Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="#"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Date Range Picker</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="#"></div>
    
</div>
 <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="well">
       <p><html>
<? var data = getData(); ?>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
<tr>
 <p>Today Report</p>
  <td class="bg-primary"style="background-color:#4885ed"><b>User Name</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"style="background-color:#4885ed"><b>Total Worked Hours</b></td>
</tr>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
</html></p>
      </div>
     <div class="well">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="bg-primary"style="background-color:#4885ed"><b>Project Name</b></td>
       <td class="bg-primary"style="background-color:#4885ed"><b>User Name</b></td>
      <td class="bg-primary"style="background-color:#4885ed"><b>Total Worked Hours</b></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>12:00:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>11:00:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test3</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>10:00:00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
      </div>  

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="well">
        <p><html>
<? var data = getData1(); ?>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
<tr>
  <p>Monthly Report</p>
  <td class="bg-primary"style="background-color:#4885ed"><b>User Name</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"style="background-color:#4885ed"><b>Total Worked Hours</b></td>
</tr>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
</html></p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="bg-primary"style="background-color:#4885ed"><b>Project Name</b></td>
       <td class="bg-primary"style="background-color:#4885ed"><b>User Name</b></td>
      <td class="bg-primary"style="background-color:#4885ed"><b>Total Worked Hours</b></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>122:00:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>211:00:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test3</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>190:00:00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
      </div>  
  <hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple html file communicating with Google Apps Script contained in a Spreadsheet.  I test it a lot as a dialog and I also run it as a web app.  The html file and the Google Apps Script communicate with each other and I pass one array from the html file to the Google Script.  Hope this helps.

The Code.gs file:

```
function doGet()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)

}

function getData(a)
{
  var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "M/d/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
  a.splice(0,0,ts);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEETID')
  ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').appendRow(a);
  return true;
}

function getURL()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEETID');
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('imgURLs');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var urlA=[];
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    urlA.push(rngA[i][0]);
  }
  return urlA;
}
```

The index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="data">
    <br />Text 1<input name="t1" type="text" size="15" id="txt1" placeholder="Text 1" />
    <br />Text 2<input name="t2" type="text" size="15" id="txt2" placeholder="Text 2" />
    <br />Text 3<input name="t3" type="text" size="15" id="txt3" placeholder="Text 3" />
    <br />Text 4<input name="t4" type="text" size="15" id="txt4" placeholder="Text 4" />
    <br /><input type="radio" name="Type" value="Member" checked />Member
    <br /><input type="radio" name="Type" value="Guest" />Guest
    <br /><input type="radio" name="Type" value="Intruder" />Intruder
    <br /><input type="button" value="submit" id="btn1" />
    <br /><img id="img1" src="" alt="img1" width="300" />
  </div>
  <div id="resp" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Response</h1>
    <p>Your data has been received.</p>
  </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#btn1').click(validate);
        $('#txt4').val('');
        $('#txt3').val('');
        $('#txt2').val('');
        $('#txt1').val('')
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(setURL)
          .getURL();
      });
      function setURL(url)
      {
        $('#img1').attr('src',url[0]);
      }
      function setResponse(a)
      {
        if(a)
        {
          $('#data').css('display','none');
          $('#resp').css('display','block');
        }
      }

      function validate()
      {
        var txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1').value || '';
        var txt2 = document.getElementById('txt2').value || '';
        var txt3 = document.getElementById('txt3').value || '';
        var txt4 = document.getElementById('txt4').value || '';
        var type = $('input[name="Type"]:checked').val();
        var a = [txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4,type];
        if(txt1 && txt2 && txt3 && txt4)
        {
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(setResponse)
            .getData(a);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
          alert('All fields must be completed.');
        }
      }

      function loadTxt(from,to)
      {
          document.getElementById(to).value = document.getElementById(from).value;
      }

      function radioValue()
      {
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('genderS');
        for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) 
        {
          if(radios[i].checked) 
          {
            return radios[i].value;
          }
        }
      }


     console.log('My Code');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```